# Purple Screen then Black Screen while Booting from CD or Windows Install

Tags: boot, radeon, boot-failure, ati

Whenever I try to run Ubuntu from my internal CD drive, I see this screen minus the Ubuntu Text:

[image]

Then the screen goes black, not even the internal light stays on. Sometimes it restarts itself, other times the black screen is indefinite until I restart the laptop myself.

I'm on an HP Quad-Core AMD A8-3500M APU with 8 GB RAM and a Radeon AMD 6620g Discrete-Graphics Card. (HP dv6-6145dx)

This is my first time using Linux, I am not too technically-inclined so any simplification would be welcomed. I am good at following technical instructions though which is how I was able to partition my hard drive and change the boot order to allow the internal CD drive first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was your problem solved or do you still need some help with this?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu have you tried? Can you try it with a recent one?

Answer (score 2):

For those that have AMD A-Series APUs, you need to get a minimal ISO for Oneiric (11.10) and then install complete system, or a Precise release newer than Alpha2 (12.04, although not recommended because it is still in development), this is because the fixes for your bug were on updates that appeared after the official release on Oneiric (11.10).

Answer (score 0):

I ordered an Acer AS5560-Sb613 to replace my wife's older Dell 1420N (Ubuntu version).  The Acer also has  an AMD A8-3500M APU with AMD Radeon HD 6620G graphics so I was looking for the answers to make it easier to install Kubuntu 11.10 on my wife's new computer. The best information I found so far is on Ubuntu Forums and although it is written for 32 bit Ubuntu, I plan on using 64 bit Kubuntu:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893523

good luck,

I will know better after I actually get to play around with the wife's new Acer AS5560-Sb613. It does appear you will need to install the proprietary drivers for the Radeon AMD 6620g to work properly.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.